# 1980s TV show or movie where kids intercept alien TV broadcast. Aliens are flat puppets. They see a gameshow and news of an Earth visit by the aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv

I've been looking for whatever this movie or show this was....

This is an OLD memory and I've not been able to find anything anywhere about it.  Some of these details might not be 100% accurate.  I was scared when I saw it, so I might have imagined details out of fear.

I believe the show was about kids accidentally intercepting an alien TV signal.   This happened because of a lightning storm or experiment or accident... something like that...

I feel like they didn't know what they were seeing at first... and had theories about what it was.

The aliens were FLAT looking creepy puppets.  Intentionally 2D-ish.  Maybe a foam appearance.    The kids saw an alien game show in their alien language and then later a news bite or broadcast which depicted some of their kind in astronaut gear visiting Earth.   The kids watching were freaked out realizing aliens were coming.

That's all I've got.   It CREEPED me out.  I was under 10 years old.

Thanks for reading - if you know what this is you'd be solving a 30+ year mystery for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are probably thinking of the episode "Fine Tuning" of *Amazing Stories* from 1985.  It can be [seen at NBC's Web site](https://www.nbc.com/amazing-stories/video/fine-tuning/2909098).  The plot summary from IMDB says:

> Three high-school kids build an antenna that can catch signals from outer space. They learn that the aliens are big fans of 1950s American television and are coming to Hollywood to meet some of their favorite Earth stars.

The aliens certainly look like unrealistic puppets in the television broadcast, and they could certainly creep one out as a child.

[image: Fine Tuning]

Immediately following this alien recreation of the George and Gracie, there is a news break showing the alien astronauts getting ready to come to Earth.

Comment: Buzz.  I am new to this forum and excuse my ignorance to any procedure.     YOU DID IT.   You solved an apparent 36 year old mystery for me.   Amazing job and I thank you very much.   They are even creepier than I remember.   The goofy box hands are where I must have got the impression of flatness.    I can't believe I was 5 years old.  Unbelievable.   Thank you again!!!

Comment: @Feisar I watched almost all the episodes of *Amazing Stories* when they were first on television, but this is one of the few that I remember clearly.  The creepiness of the aliens probably had a lot to do that.

Comment: I just finished watching it.  It definitely shifts gears after the part I described !! 
Thanks again for finding this - and now I'll move on to deal with whatever mental health issues I've caused myself (.. or rid myself of?) by finally putting this to bed.

Comment: The alien on the right apparently tries to look like Asimov.